# Error al cargar Layouts en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema a la hora de cargar los layouts en mi proyecto Android.

En la cabecera de "activity_main.xml" tengo lo siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.nameproject"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.nameproject.MainActivity">
```

Y me muestra este error:

```
Error:(65) No resource identifier found for attribute 'lay' in package 'android'
```

¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: lo cerraste? es decir: </LinearLayout>

Comment: Sí, está cerrado...

Comment: MR987 como hiciste para solucionar tu problema ?
explícame por favor, tengo el mismo problema ahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que describes:

> Error:(65) No resource identifier found for attribute 'lay' in package
>   'android'

Indica que **Lay** no pertenece a ningún atributo en Android. Debes revisar tus layouts para saber si en verdad tienes definida esta propiedad.

También algo importante a corregir, el `namespace` usado es incorrecto:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.nameproject
```

el correcto debe ser:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

probablemente esto sea la causa.

Comment: El problema es que he utilizado el namespace:
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Y me aparece sombreado, como en gris, Y con el siguiente mensaje:
"Namespace declaration is never used"
Por eso he probado con otro tipo de declaración.

Por otro lado, no tengo ningún "Lay" en mis Layouts, es como si no cargara correctamente los archivos.

Comment: @MR987 ok si te aparece sombreado en gris es que no es necesario agregarlo ya que no contienes un elemento en el layout que lo utilice. En cuanto a Lay te sugiero agregues el layout completo.

Comment: Solucionado!! gracias!